# How to have a conditionnal redirect in every functon of my controller, Symfony 5 PHP 7?

Tags: php, symfony5

I have a project in Symfony 5 / PHP 7.4 which requires an attribute in session for a specific logic to work. This attribute is set on the "set_session_attribute_page" page. So I have this chunk of code in every function of my controller:

```
$attribute = $this->session->get('attribute');
if (!isset($attribute)) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute("set_session_attribute_page");
}
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to process this verification ?

Comment: Look into symfony events. `kernel.request` or `kernel.controller`

Comment: Examples of using the kernel events can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#creating-an-event-subscriber)